# Connect DocumentDB with SNS topic without middleware

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-documentdb

Is there any configuration possible to transparently connect an AWS DocumentDB with an AWS SNS topic so that when something is written in the DocumentDB, the same entry gets published in the SNS topic as a consequence?

We are searching for an option to do this without middleware: no lambdas in the middle for example, to keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, that would slow down your process. You do need a middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting AWS support regarding this, their response is:

> Although the service role(AWSServiceRoleForRDS) associated with AWS
>   DocumentDB consists of an Amazon SNS publish action ([DocumentDB
>   Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/developerguide.pdf), pg:273), it does need a middleware to trigger the
>   publish action to an SNS topic